# name variable at the same time using complete

Tags: r, dplyr, group-by, cut

I would like to get a sub total by age group. The sample data and the codes are:

```
set.seed(12345)

#create a numeric variable Age       
AGE <- sample(0:110, 100, replace = TRUE)

# Creat Data fame
Sample.data <-data.frame(AGE)

summary_data<- Sample.data %>% 
  group_by(grp = cut(
    AGE,
    breaks=c(-Inf, 0,0.001, 0.083, 2, 13, 65,1000),
    right=TRUE,
    labels = c("Foetus(0 yr)","Neonate (0.001 - 0.082 yr)","Infant(0.083-1.999 yrs)","Child(2-12.999 yrs)", "Adolescent(13-17.999 yrs)","Adult(18-64.999 yrs.)","Elderly(65-199 yrs)")
  )) %>% summarise("Total People" = n())%>% complete(grp = levels(grp), fill = list("Total People = 0))
```

which gave the results that looks like this:

[image]

Is it possible to label grp as "Age Group"? and sort it by age?

I tried to define the name as follow and the results are strange. What did I do wrong?

```
summary_data<- Sample.data %>% 
  group_by("Age Group" = cut(
    AGE,
    breaks=c(-Inf, 0,0.001, 0.083, 2, 13, 65,1000),
    right=TRUE,
    labels = c("Foetus(0 yr)","Neonate (0.001 - 0.082 yr)","Infant(0.083-1.999 yrs)","Child(2-12.999 yrs)", "Adolescent(13-17.999 yrs)","Adult(18-64.999 yrs.)","Elderly(65-199 yrs)")
  )) %>% summarise("Total People" = n())%>% complete("Age Group" = levels("Age Group"), fill = list("Total People" = 0))
```

The new results are:

[image]

The variable now has name "Age Group", but table doesn't fill 0 for the age category that do not have observation.  What should I do.

The ideal results should look like this:

[image]

Comment: I assume that you are `arrange`ing by 'Total People' at the end

Comment: I am thinking of arrange data by the age group (Neonate to Elderly)

Comment: but shouldn't Foetus come first? Thats how you defined your labels

Comment: @StupidWolf My bad. You are correct. Foebtus should come first.

Comment: I could sort of solve it by changing the age groups labels, like this:```summary_data<- Sample.data %>% 
  group_by("Age Group"= cut(
    AGE,
    breaks=c(-Inf, 0,0.001, 0.083, 2, 13, 65,1000),
    right=TRUE,
    labels = c("(0 yr)Foetus","(0.001 - 0.082 yr)Neonate","(0.083-1.999 yrs)Infant","(2-12.999 yrs)Child", "(13-17.999 yrs)Adolescent","(18-64.999 yrs.)Adult","(65-199 yrs)Elderly")
  )) %>% summarise("Total People" = n()) %>% complete("Age Group" = levels(`Age Group`), fill = list("Total People" = 0))``` But it looks silly . Any better suggestion?

Comment: Also I got the warning message: Warning message:
Column `Age Group` joining character vector and factor, coercing into character vector . Is it sth that i need to be concerned? what should I do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can change the double quotes to backquotes in `levels` to evaluate the column in `complete`.  The column name is non-standard i.e. it includes a space.

```
 ...
  %>%
   complete("Age Group" = levels(`Age Group`), fill = list("Total People" = 0))
# A tibble: 7 x 2
#  `Age Group`                `Total People`
#  <chr>                               <dbl>
#1 Adolescent(13-17.999 yrs)              14
#2 Adult(18-64.999 yrs.)                  37
#3 Child(2-12.999 yrs)                     2
#4 Elderly(65-199 yrs)                    46
#5 Foetus(0 yr)                            1
#6 Infant(0.083-1.999 yrs)                 0
#7 Neonate (0.001 - 0.082 yr)              0
```

---

If we want to `arrange`

```
Sample.data %>% 
   group_by("Age Group" = cut(
     AGE,
     breaks=c(-Inf, 0,0.001, 0.083, 2, 13, 65,1000),
     right=TRUE,
     labels = c("Foetus(0 yr)","Neonate (0.001 - 0.082 yr)","Infant(0.083-1.999 yrs)","Child(2-12.999 yrs)", "Adolescent(13-17.999 yrs)","Adult(18-64.999 yrs.)","Elderly(65-199 yrs)")
   )) %>% 
     summarise("Total People" = n()) %>%
     complete("Age Group" = levels(`Age Group`), fill = list("Total People" = 0)) %>%
     arrange(`Total People`)
```

Comment: You rock! I was thinking I am the only one skipping dinner and running r. You are so kind to answering my question at such late time. Many thanks.